# How to import Multiple realm in keycloak?

Tags: keycloak

I have two different realms and I've to import different configs by realm JSON for both of them(i.e import both realm).

I created Docker compose for that above said.

here is the code.

```
version: "3"
services:
  keycloak:
    image: jboss/keycloak
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - "/Users/msn/Downloads/:/Users/msn/Downloads/"
    environment:
      - "KEYCLOAK_USER=admin"
      - "KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin"
      - "KEYCLOAK_IMPORT=/Users/msn/Downloads/realm-export.json,/Users/msn/Downloads/realm-expor.json"
```

but it imports only first JSON not the second please suggest the solutions to import both of the realms.

Answer (score 4):

```
version: "3"
services:
  keycloak:
    image: jboss/keycloak
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - "/Users/msn/Downloads/:/Users/msn/Downloads/"
    environment:
      - "KEYCLOAK_USER=admin"
      - "KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin"
      #- "KEYCLOAK_IMPORT=/Users/msn/Downloads/realm-export.json,/Users/msn/Downloads/realm-expor.json"
    command:
      - "-b 0.0.0.0"
      - "-Dkeycloak.migration.action=import"
      - "-Dkeycloak.migration.provider=singleFile"
      - "-Dkeycloak.migration.file=/Users/msn/Downloads/realm-export.json"
      - "-Dkeycloak.migration.strategy=IGNORE_EXISTING"
```

note: all your realms have to be in the same file "realm-export.json".

Comment: Thankyou haythem but I need to import realms of two different .json file.

Answer (score 3):

put both of your realms to one `.json` file where content is array. So:

```
[
{...realm1...},
{...realm2...}
]
```

**EDIT:**
Maybe you will need to adjust some parameters. I'm working only with Dockerfile so here is content of it. I hope it will help you.

```
FROM jboss/keycloak:9.0.2
COPY "src/main/jib/opt/jboss/keycloak/imports/realm.json" "/opt/jboss/keycloak/imports/realm.json"
CMD ["-Dkeycloak.migration.action=import", "-Dkeycloak.migration.provider=singleFile", "-Dkeycloak.migration.file=/opt/jboss/keycloak/imports/realm.json", "-Dkeycloak.migration.strategy=IGNORE_EXISTING"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Working on Keycloak 12.0.4 (import multiple realms in separated files)

This is from a Dockerfile, but you can easily use the same configuration in a docker-compose.

### Dockerfile

First the realm files must be copied into the container

```yaml
COPY keycloak-files/realm-config/* /opt/jboss/keycloak/realm-config/
```

Now I can configure the JAVA_OPTS environment variable, to include:

```sh
ENV JAVA_OPTS -server \
 -Xms1303m \
 -Xmx1303m \
 -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M \
 -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m \
 -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman \
 -Djava.awt.headless=true \
 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true \
 -Dkeycloak.migration.action=import \
 -Dkeycloak.migration.provider=dir \
 -Dkeycloak.migration.dir=/opt/jboss/keycloak/realm-config \
 -Dkeycloak.migration.strategy=OVERWRITE_EXISTING
```

The important lines are prefixed by `keycloak.migration.`- Here we set the migration dir (where files will be imported from) to be equal as the one where we copied files before.

### Docker-compose

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  keycloak:
    image: jboss/keycloak:12.0.4
    command:
      [
        '-b',
        '0.0.0.0',
        '-Dkeycloak.migration.action=import',
        '-Dkeycloak.migration.provider=dir',
        '-Dkeycloak.migration.dir=/opt/jboss/keycloak/realm-config',
        '-Dkeycloak.migration.strategy=OVERWRITE_EXISTING',
      ]
    volumes:
      - ./keycloak-files/realm-config:/opt/jboss/keycloak/realm-config

...
```

Basically it's the same.

You can copy any json file inside realm-config and it should be imported.

It's possible to use `IGNORE_EXISTING` migration strategy to avoid overwriting.

Comment: See here how to export to multiple files which also includes users for each realm: https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-documentation/blob/master/server_admin/topics/export-import.adoc

Answer (score 1):

Complementing answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/61794091/6039697

1. Export all your realms into json files
2. Put them in a directory e.g. `realms`
3. Mount `realms` directory inside the container using a volume
4. Put all mounted files absolute paths into the env `KEYCLOAK_IMPORT` separating them by a comma.

```
.
├── docker-compose.yaml
└── realms
    ├── realm-1.json
    └── realm-2.json

1 directory, 3 files
```

```yaml
version: '2.2'

services:
  keycloak:
    image: jboss/keycloak:6.0.1
    hostname: keycloak
    environment:
      KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
      KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: admin
      DB_VENDOR: h2
      DB_DATABASE: keycloak
      KEYCLOAK_IMPORT: /tmp/realms/realm-1.json,/tmp/realms/realm-2.json
    volumes:
      - ./realms:/tmp/realms
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    expose:
      - 8080
```

Answer (score 0):

The following suggestions are tested for Keycloak 16.1.1 ([jboss/keycloak image](https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak/)) and based on the [Importing and exporting the database](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#assembly-exporting-importing_server_administration_guide) chapter from the official Keycloak docs.

### Naming convention

As we can read in the docs:

> When importing from a directory, the filenames must follow this naming convention:
>
> - <REALM_NAME>-realm.json. For example, "acme-roadrunner-affairs-realm.json" for the realm named "acme-roadrunner-affairs".

In my example project I have two realms: `Example-Realm` and `keep-growing`. Therefore, the import files are named respecitvely: `Example-Realm-realm.json` and `keep-growing-realm.json`.

### Volume mapping

Make sure that the volume that maps files from your machine contains all the import files. My example volume config from the `docker-compose.yml` file:

```yaml
version: '3.3'
services:
  keycloak:
    …
    volumes:
      - ./keycloak/realms/import:/tmp/import
    …
```

The `./keycloak/realms/import` on my machine contains:
[image]

As a result, after restarting the docker instance, I can see all the files from the aforementioned location on my machine available in the container:
[image]

### Minimal import config

I added the following commands to my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```yaml
version: '3.3'
services:
  keycloak:
    …
    volumes:
       …
    command:
      - "-Dkeycloak.migration.action=import"
      - "-Dkeycloak.migration.provider=dir"
      - "-Dkeycloak.migration.dir=/tmp/import"
```

This will import realms on the container startup and overwrite existing ones.

### Verify logs

You should see the following entries in the container logs when starting the container:

```
INFO  [org.keycloak.exportimport.dir.DirImportProvider] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) Importing from directory /tmp/import
…
INFO  [org.keycloak.services] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) KC-SERVICES0050: Initializing master realm
INFO  [org.keycloak.services] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) KC-SERVICES0030: Full model import requested. Strategy: OVERWRITE_EXISTING
INFO  [org.keycloak.exportimport.util.ImportUtils] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) Realm 'keep-growing' imported
INFO  [org.keycloak.exportimport.util.ImportUtils] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) Realm 'Example-Realm' imported
INFO  [org.keycloak.services] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) KC-SERVICES0032: Import finished successfully
```

### Verify imported realms in the Keycloak Admin Console

All imported realms are available in the admin console:
[image]

### For reference

The complete `docker-compose.yml` file:

```yaml
version: '3.3'
services:
  keycloak:
    image: jboss/keycloak:${KEYCLOAK_VERSION}
    ports:
      - "8024:8080"
    environment:
      - KEYCLOAK_USER=${KEYCLOAK_USER}
      - KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=${KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - ./keycloak/realms/import:/tmp/import
    command:
      - "-Dkeycloak.migration.action=import"
      - "-Dkeycloak.migration.provider=dir"
      - "-Dkeycloak.migration.dir=/tmp/import"
```

The `.env` file:

```
KEYCLOAK_VERSION=16.1.1
KEYCLOAK_USER=keycloak
KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=keycloak
```

EDIT: I wrote more on Keycloak directory import in the [Keycloak in Docker #6 - How to import realms from a directory](https://keepgrowing.in/tools/keycloak-in-docker-6-how-to-import-realms-from-a-directory/) post.