# Configuring Keycloak to use multiple realms in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, keycloak

I`m currently using the jboss/keycloak:12.0.4 container within my Kubernetes cluster with a single realm configuration. The configuration file is mounted through an configmap.
The config file currently looks like {...realm1...}. Now I need three more realms and I have [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61184888/how-to-import-multiple-realm-in-keycloak), that I can put multiple realm configs into an array.

```
[
{...realm1...},
{...realm2...}
]
```

Unfortunately this is not working on my side. The containers are crashing and in the logs I get the error message: "Error during startup: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to parse json". I saw that people are adding the option `-Dkeycloak.migration.provider=singleFile` to their docker commands, but I don't have those for Kubernetes that way. How can i achieve to include multiple realms?

Comment: What is look like your config map? Please attach it to the question. It is possible that you have some character hidden in it that destroys the validity of json.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using `jboss/keycloak:12.0.4` I am assuming that you set `KEYCLOAK_IMPORT` environment variable, right?

The docker container [maps this environment variable](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-containers/blob/12.0.4/server/tools/docker-entrypoint.sh#L71) to `-Dkeycloak.import=...`.

If you want to import multiple realms this way, you may simply want to add each realm into a single file and add them as a comma-seperated list.

So `KEYCLOAK_IMPORT=/tmp/realm1.json,/tmp/realm2.json` becomes `-Dkeycloak.import=/tmp/realm1.json,/tmp/realm2.json`

For details please see the [server administration guide](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#_export_import) (scroll down to end of chapter `Export and Import`).

You may also want to checkout [Keycloak operator](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-operator) which provides a [CRD for KeycloakRealms](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-operator/blob/master/deploy/crds/keycloak.org_keycloakrealms_crd.yaml).

Comment: I was a little confused that we pass the different files as a comma separated string and not as an array. But it works; thank you!